# How to parse Next page data into same listview.builder in flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter

I am able to parse JSON data by from Unsplash API but I only get to show 20 items. is there any way to parse next page in the same listview.builder with scroll and make it infinite.

Comment: simply get your paged json data in `ListView.builder#itemBuilder` (use `MapCache` for asynchronous data access) - that way you will request the data on demand when you scroll your `ListView`

Comment: Any reference code or something

Comment: after two weeks? sorry, i got one but i deleted it